# Handle different dataSources with only one material table component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using Angular for building my website - It is just a bit testing to get familiar with Angular.

Currently I am stuck at how to display data properly ... I installed Material and I am using Material table. I can display the data of one source via my Material Table, which I created.

To do this, I created two components: One component which contains a form to create new data entrys and the second one which contains the table. Now I want to create a third component (another form again), which should display data using the same Material table component but from another API call from another service than the first form component.

Is it possible to handle different API calls with only one Material Table component and the dataSource attribute of the table or do I have to create a table component for each form component? I dont think that this is the way to do

Unfortunately I dont have an approach to start, so I cant show you what I already tried ... I would be thankful if someone tells me the best-practice how to handle such a situation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure. It doesn't matter if you use a material table or any other component. I would share the generic idea, I suppose it is enough.

I suppose you have `source` property that contains data and it is bound to the material table somewhat like this:

```html
<mat-table [source]='source"></mat-table>
```

When the component is initing you can place a logic to choose what to use as a source based on some parameter. I can imagine it could be a query parameter or route parameter. An example with query param:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   source$: Observable<MyData[]>();

   constructor(private service1, private service2, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
        this.source$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
            pluck(QueryParamNames.dataSourceType),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map(async (dataSourceType: DataSourceType) => {
                if (dataSourceType === DataSourceType.one) {
                    return this.service1.getData();
                } else {
                    return this.service2.getData();
                }
            }),
        );
   }
}
```

```html
<mat-table [source]='source$ | async"></mat-table>
```

I also leveraged the `async` pipe to avoid hustle with subscriptions and memory leaks. `async` pipe is great for it.